# Setting variables from shell: how to use them in a script?

Tags: shell-script, variable

How can I set variables to be used in scripts as well? They don't have to be global / system-wide, just the current session is sufficient. But for some reason they seem gone even if I run a script right from my current terminal.

Example:

```bash
foo=bar
echo "$foo"
```

output: `bar`

However if test.sh contains `echo "$foo"` and I do:

```
foo=bar
./test.sh
```

The output is empty. How do I set a scope for temporary variables with a terminal session that remains valid when executing scripts from that same session?

Comment: One could also set a variable that is already a variable in a shell script. For example: `export TASKDDATA=$TASKDDATA`. Where the `$TASKDDATA` for example has been set earlier with `TASKDDATA=/var/taskd`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`export foo=bar` will set the environment variable `foo` to the string `bar`. You can also use `foo=bar ./test.sh` as a single command to set `foo` to `bar` for `test.sh` (i.e. it avoids setting the variable in the local shell session).

Answer (score 12):

When you run your shell script, it executes in a new shell instance, and does not inherit any variables instantiated in the interactive shell instance.

Specific variables can be inherited this way, called environment variables. You make a variable assignment an environment variable by using `export`, such as `export foo=bar`. This is the bash syntax, other shells may use `env` or some other method.

You can also cause the shell script to execute in the same shell instance by 'sourcing' it. You can do this with `. test.sh` (note the period) or using `source test.sh`. You can do this in your interactive session, or you can do this from within a shell script. This is really handy for creating shell "libraries", where you source in a set of shell functions or variable definitions from an external file. Super handy.

For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /path/lib.sh
echo $foo # foo is instantiated in lib.sh
do_something # this is a shell function from lib.sh
```

where lib.sh is:

```
foo="bar"
do_something() {
echo "I am do_something"
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that sourcing arbitrary scripts is *not* a good idea—you should fully understand what they may do to your environment first—but I agree that setting up a function "library" is a very handy use for `source`ing.  Nicely explained.

Comment: Is there a way to export variables from the script session to the outside terminal session?

Comment: @Royi that's **exactly** what  `source`'ing does, as explained in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be to pass the variable to your script as an argument.

```
foo=bar
./test.sh $foo
```

The issue then becomes the contents of ./test.sh

It would have to `echo $1` instead of `echo $foo` - the $1 indicating the first argument passed to the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the assignment and echo test script in the same shell.

```
root@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~# export foo=bar
root@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~# cat test.sh 
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "$foo"
root@ijaz-HP-EliteBook-8560p:~# ./test.sh 
bar
```

this is just one way of doing it.